# Is it possible to define boolean expressions that can be evaluated later?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, lazy-evaluation

Looking to achieve a sort of dynamic expression where I can later evaluate the booleans if called.

```
condition &&= condition2; //not evaluated just yet
condition ||= condition3;    

if (condition)    //evaluated now
   do this;
else
   do this;
```

for example I am the using the same conditions throughout my code and it would be easier if I could just adjust the one statement or add more to it even when the programs running.

```
conditions = (x>50 && y>200) && (type == MONKEY);
conditions &&= (x<75 && y<250);
```

and later on in the code

```
if (conditions)
    cout<<"Hello!";
```

edit: The conditions should be evaluated at the if statement.

Comment: You can use operator `&=`

Comment: So I'm just wondering with the answers below aren't these evaluating the expressions at the assignment and not the if statements? I am looking for functionality that evaluates at the if statement.

Comment: Interesting. Why? i.e. why do  you care when things are evaulated? Is there a threading context we don't know about?

Comment: Well its just a really simple program, but what I'm doing is going through several For-loops and avoiding certain situations. But I keep finding more of these situations and it would be easier to just have them set in one place. **Example**: moving through pixels in a window and avoiding certain areas of the window.
But overall I'm just interested to see if this is possible.

Comment: If you're moving, write a move function, like move left etc and jump over these bits - or stay still, or whatever?

Answer (score 2):

**Be very careful when working with && and &**

---

Reason 1

Expanding the postulated (and syntactically invalid)

```
condition &&= condition2;
```

to

```
condition = condition && condition2;
```

reveals a subtlety: `condition2` will **not** be evaluated if `condition` is `false`.

---

Reason 2

`&` and `&&` also have differing behaviour for integral types, e.g. `0b01 & 0b10` is `0` but `0b01 && 0b10` is `true` (here I'm using C++14 binary literals).

---

Conclusion

So I'd favour the compaction

```
if (condition = condition && condition2){
    // do this
} else {
    // do this
}
```

where `condition2` is only evaluated if `condition` is `true`

Comment: Not to mention there are types contextually convertible to `bool` that might explode with `&=`

Comment: @PasserBy: Indeed. Added that to the end.

Comment: IIRC short circuiting applies only to non user defined types, no? So if one where to make a deferred_bool then there won't be any issues regarding `&=` vs `&&` if implemented properly

Comment: Not correct. Short circuiting is only dropped if && is *overloaded* for the type. Rather than do all that, you may as well write `foo(condition, condition2)` that takes the conditions by reference and const reference respectively, modifies the first argument, and returns `condition`.

Answer (score 2):

The sensible solution here is to create named functions for those conditions and call them whenever necessary.

---

That said ...

> Is it possible [..]

*Of course*. To defer evaluation, just wrap your conditions in (lambda) functions. Proof of concept:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename F, typename G>
auto and_also (F f, G g) {
  return [=]() {
    bool first = f();
    if (! first) return false;
    return static_cast<bool>(g());
  };
}

int main () {
  int dummy = -1;
  std::function<bool()> condition = [&](){return dummy > 0;};
  condition = and_also(condition, [&](){return dummy < 42;});
  dummy = 21;
  if (condition()) std::cout << "in range" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to address the use case, you've mentioned in a comment:

> Example: moving through pixels in a window and avoiding certain areas of the window.

For reasons of readability, I'd recommend you define a function, e.g., like this (pseudocode) example:

```
bool is_in_rect(point2i p, rect2i rect) {
    // check x range
    if (p.x >= rect.x1 && p.x < rect.x2)
        return true;
    // check y range
    if (p.y >= rect.y1 && p.y < rect.y2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

You can add functions for specialized situations as you wish:

```
bool is_in_monkey_rect(point2i p, rect2i rect) {
    return rect.type == MONKEY && is_in_rect(p, rect);
}
```

> But overall I'm just interested to see if this is possible.

Other than delegating to a function, you'd probably use macros to simulate this kind of lazy evaluation. But I wouldn't recommend that.

Note that, depending on the actual nature of the problem, it might make more sense to adapt the iteration pattern, rather than iterating all the data and check every single pixel for relevance.

Comment: Indeed. I was trying not to think of the M word.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do something in one place, so  you don't repeat yourself everywhere is to make a function.

For example,

```
bool special_condition(bool current_condition, int x)
{
    return current_condition && (x<75 && y<250);
}
```

allows this whenever needed.

```
if (special_condition(conditions))
    do_something();
else
    do_something_else();
```

This will be evaulated when the if is encountered, however, this won't short circuit if current_condition is false when the function will still be called.

Comment: I think something along the lines of this is what I am after. I could create a recursive function and make it test all the conditions.

Comment: The lack of short circuit may slow you down... it depends on your context.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer Stefan, in C++ no.

The expression is evaluated during `&=`.

Short circuiting expressions e.g. ignoring `b` if `a` is false in expressions such as `a && b`, is usually configurable in your environment and normally on.

If you still wish to do so, create an evaluation function instead.

/Anders